# glDrawElements GL ERROR type = 0x824c, severity = 0x9146, message = GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

OpenGl version 330 core

I have this error when call `glDrawElements`, BUT only at the first call in the main loop !!
in fact the code (below) work fine !.

I know the meaning of this error :

> is generated if a non-zero buffer object name is bound to an enabled array or the element array and the buffer object's data store is currently mapped.

I want to understand why only at the first call of `glDrawElement` "trow" this error!

In the code, `Mesh::Init()`, initialize buffer and `Mesh::Draw()` call `glDrawElement`

```
void Mesh::init() {

size_t vtx     = vertices.size() * sizeof(vec4);
size_t vtx_col = verticesColor.size() * sizeof(vec4);
size_t nrm     = normals.size() * sizeof(vec3);
size_t tng     = tangent.size() * sizeof(vec3);
size_t btng    = bitangent.size() * sizeof(vec3);
size_t txc     = text_coord.size() * sizeof(vec2);

size_t total = vtx + vtx_col + nrm + tng + btng + txc;


glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, (indices.size() * sizeof(unsigned int)), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);  
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, total, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,  0                            , vtx,     &vertices[0]);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,  vtx                          , nrm,     &normals[0]);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (vtx + nrm)                   , txc,     &text_coord[0]);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (vtx + nrm + txc)             , tng,     &tangent[0]);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (vtx + nrm + txc + tng)       , btng,    &bitangent[0]);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (vtx + nrm + txc + tng + btng), vtx_col, &verticesColor[0]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);    


glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);    
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);

        glVertexAttribPointer(loc.vertex,  4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*) (0));
        glVertexAttribPointer(loc.normals,   3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*) (vtx));
        glVertexAttribPointer(loc.texCoord,  2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*) (vtx + nrm));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc.vertex);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc.normals);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc.texCoord);

        if(flag_TngBtg)   {
            glVertexAttribPointer(loc.tangent,   3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*) (vtx + nrm + txc));
            glVertexAttribPointer(loc.bitangent, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*) (vtx + nrm + txc + tng));
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc.tangent);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc.bitangent);
        }

        if(flag_VtxColor)   {
            glVertexAttribPointer(loc.vertex_color, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*) (vtx + nrm + txc + tng + btng));
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc.vertex_color);
        }

glBindVertexArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

}
```

---

```
void Mesh::draw() {

glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (const GLvoid*)0);
glBindVertexArray(0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have foud the problem "in this way" at the moment..

When my program load a model 3D file with Assimp, before initializing the Mesh class , Mesh::init() , the texture are loaded first

```
unsigned int textureID;
            glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
            .......
```

at the end of loading and bindign texture just put:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

in this way glDrawElements NOT "trow" any error.